# error in sign-in at Create Transaction blockcypher/php-client

Tags: php, laravel, bitcoin, block-cipher

here my code for create and sign and send

```
  $request = clone $tx;
/// For Sample Purposes Only.
    $params = array(
           'includeToSignTx' => 1,
           'script_type'=>'mutlisig-n-of-m',
        );
$txClient = new TXClient($apiContext);

try {

  // dd($tx);
    $txSkeleton = $txClient->create($tx,$params);
    $privateKeys = array("private key");
$txSkeleton = $txClient->sign($txSkeleton, $privateKeys);
$txSkeleton = $txClient->send($txSkeleton);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    dd("Created TX", "TXSkeleton", null, $request, $ex);
    exit(1);
}
```

This is the error i got:

> FatalThrowableError in PrivateKeyList.php line 54: Type error:
>   Argument 1 passed to
>   BlockCypher\Crypto\PrivateKeyList::addPrivateKey() must be an instance
>   of BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyInterface, instance of
>   BitWasp\Bitcoin\Crypto\EcAdapter\Impl\PhpEcc\Key\PrivateKey given,
>   called in
>   /home/pixel/Documents/tests/vendor/blockcypher/php-client/lib/BlockCypher/Crypto/PrivateKeyList.php
>   on line 43

here is code

```
public function addPrivateKey(PrivateKeyInterface $privateKey)
{
   $pubKeyHex = $privateKey->getPublicKey()->getHex();
   $this->privateKeys[$pubKeyHex] = $privateKey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly is wrong with so little information, but from the error it's clear what you passed in as `$privateKey` is the incorrect type. Work back from here to the code that calls this function.

Verify that `BitWasp\Bitcoin\Crypto\EcAdapter\Impl\PhpEcc\Key\PrivateKey` implements the interface `BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyInterface`

Comment: what information do you need? and also please explain verify part

Comment: Like the code that is calling that function for starters. That will give an idea of where the problem is coming from. And I mean look at the class that is getting passed in as the parameter. It is clearly not of the expected interface type. Where did it come from?

Comment: I don't see anything that calls `addPrivateKey` in there. is it related to this `$txSkeleton = $txClient->sign($txSkeleton, $privateKeys);`

Comment: yes there is the error came, actual code is this rest is package that i install

Comment: Ok, there still isnt enough information to determine anything. Can you step into the function or get a logging statement in there to see what is happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164169/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-btl).